# How to add a new contact to contacts using phone gap?

Tags: cordova

I am new to Phone gap .Any one please tel me How to add a new  contact to contacts using phone gap?

Thanks,

Comment: You might want to accept an answer if your query is resolved by any, or else post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4):

To access contacts, you need to use the contacts plugin of PhoneGap.

To add this plugin to the project all we need to do is:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts
```

To configure platform specific configuration settings we need to add the following code:

For Android:
In app/res/xml/config.xml:

```
<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
</feature>
```

In app/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

For iOS:
In config.xml:

```
<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
</feature>
```

For Windows Phone:
    In Properties/WPAppManifest.xml:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS" />
</Capabilities>
```

And to finally add a contact from through JavaScript:

```
var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "The New Contact"});
var name = new ContactName();
name.givenName = "Jane";
name.familyName = "Doe";
myContact.name = name;

var phoneNumbers = [];
phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('work', '212-555-1234', false);
phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('mobile', '917-555-5432', true); // preferred number
phoneNumbers[2] = new ContactField('home', '203-555-7890', false);
myContact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;

myContact.note = "Example note for the newly added contact";

myContact.save(onSuccessCallBack, onErrorCallBack);

function onSuccessCallBack(contact) {
    alert("Save Success");
};

function onErrorCallBack(contactError) {
    alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
};
```

Properties of a contact:

- id: A globally unique identifier. (DOMString)
- displayName: The name of this Contact, suitable for display to end users. (DOMString)
- name: An object containing all components of a persons name. (ContactName)
- nickname: A casual name by which to address the contact. (DOMString)
- phoneNumbers: An array of all the contact's phone numbers. (ContactField[])
- emails: An array of all the contact's email addresses. (ContactField[])
- addresses: An array of all the contact's addresses. (ContactAddress[])
- ims: An array of all the contact's IM addresses. (ContactField[])
- organizations: An array of all the contact's organizations. (ContactOrganization[])
- birthday: The birthday of the contact. (Date)
- note: A note about the contact. (DOMString)
- photos: An array of the contact's photos. (ContactField[])
- categories: An array of all the user-defined categories associated with the contact. (ContactField[])
- urls: An array of web pages associated with the contact. (ContactField[])

For more information [PhoneGap API Documentation - Contacts](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can go through [HELP OF PHONEGAP FOR CONTCTS](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html). I think its good and enough documentation for add new contact to contacts.

Comment: i have gone through that api am able to add a name of the contact but am not able to add number, address, emailid ...

Comment: @YerramNaveen ... please share code .. how to you add name into contact.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at 
http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/,let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

Refer [**Phonegap Document - Create Contact**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.create)

Following is the sample code to create new contact.

```
var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
```

store contact phone numbers in ContactField[]

```
var phoneNumbers = [];
phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('work', '212-555-1234', false);
phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('mobile', '917-555-5432', true); // preferred number
phoneNumbers[2] = new ContactField('home', '203-555-7890', false);
contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
```

To save the contact

```
contact.save();
```